# How can I deserialize an NServiceBus XML message?

Tags: .net, xml, serialization, nservicebus

I have a .NET console application that is performing sending a message to a bus on another machine. using the code:

```
Bus.Send(MyMessageClass);
```

I now want to be able to take the XML and deserialize the message back to the C# object MyMessageClass. This is to allow me to write an acceptance test on the properties that are set and sent on the message. I can get the message into the System.Messaging.Message() object and then get an XML document from the BodyStream of this instance, but I cannot correctly deserialize this.

I would like to do this using the NServiceBus.Serializers.XML.XmlMessageSerializer() object (not the .NET framework's XmlSerializer() object) if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to troubleshoot serialization of a message at one point in the past, so have this old unit test.  Might be enough to get you started, but IIRC it has to run in the context of a running bus, otherwise the message type won't be registered with the serializer (which I think happens when the bus is bootstrapped).

```
    [Test]
    public void TestMyMessage()
    {
        var test = new MyMessage();

        var serializer = new XmlMessageSerializer(new MessageMapper());

        var messages = new object[] {test};

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(messages, stream);
            stream.Position = 0;

            object[] msg = serializer.Deserialize(stream);

            Assert.NotNull(msg[0]);
            Assert.IsTrue(msg[0] is MyMessage);
        }
    }
```

It may be worthwhile to poke around in the NSB Unit tests for XML Serialization [here](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/tree/develop/src/NServiceBus.Core.Tests/Serializers/XML).

Comment: This was extremely helpful to me thank you. I found the answer from their tests in GitHub and I now have the test working.